# Do I need a virtual destructor if descendant classes have no non-static members or destructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-destructor

I'm playing around with a class hierarchy for file descriptors, where the base class holds an int and calls `close` on it during destruction and child classes don't add any virtual methods or data members, just differ in their construction (e.g. the `named_file_filedes` takes a path and initializes the base with `open` in the ctor) or non-virtual member functions (e.g. you can only call `kevent` on a `kqueue_filedes`). Given this, does the base class need a virtual destructor? The size of the child classes is all the same and none of them have custom destruction logic. Tagged `c++11` as that's the standard version I'm targeting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `delete` derived classes via pointers to base classes then the behavior will be undefined without a virtual destructor, no matter how the derived classes look.

C++11 Standard, §5.3.5/3:

> If the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

However, if the classes differ only in their constructor, consider using alternatives to derivation, e.g. simple free functions like `create_named_file()`.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a `virtual` destructor if you intend to destroy a derived class object by `delete`ing a base class pointer.  Such as:

```
class Foo {};
class Bar : public Foo {}

int main()
{
  Foo* f = new Bar;
  delete f; // << UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR without virtual destructor in base classe
}
```

You'll also need at least 1 `virtual` method in the base if you require the object to be polymorphic -- for instance, if you intend to use `dynamic_cast` to go from base to derived.  Commonly a virtual destructor is provided in this case.  Having only a virtual destructor is sufficient to ensure the class is polymorphic.